# Next.js layout.tsx vs template.tsx in app router. How to use them?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router, next.js14

Lets say we have

```
/app
   /[testParam]
      layout.tsx
      template.tsx
      page.tsx
...
```

I expect each of them get the same props

```
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  params: {
    testParam: string;
  };
}
```

But template actually doesn't – it gets no params. ***Why a template never get params, but just a children?***

[Next.js template docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#templates) says "Templates are similar to layouts... But creates a new instance for each of their children on navigation". But it's not similar, it doesn't have access to params. Is it by design? Am i missed some configuration or misunderstood the docs?

Glad for any thoughts on this. Thank you!